# How can i move values from one column to another column row-wise?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
                                   preference                     Other
588                                       NaN       goes to work with sister
461                                       NaN                    google
88                                        NaN                 bybus, mobike
44                                        NaN                      TMB
141                                       NaN                     Smou
741                                       NaN                     Scoot
90                                        NaN                  SDFASDAF
612                                       NaN            Reby (electric scooter)
217                                       NaN                    Moovit
453                                       NaN                   Leasing
427                                       NaN                   Leasing
162                                       NaN                   LEASING
247                                       NaN                 JUSTMOOVE
459                                       NaN                  Free now
131                                       NaN                     Drivy
510                                       NaN                    Car2go
185                                       NaN                    Cabify
742                                       NaN                    Cabify
557                                       NaN                public transport
0                                      No app                      NaN
1                                         NaN                      NaN
2                                      No app                      NaN
3                                      No app                      NaN
```

I want to move the first 19 values only from the column `Other` to the column `preference`. This dataframe is a subset of a bigger one and is sorted by the column `Other` in descending way to get this result.

I have tried this:

```
df[["preference", "Other"]].sort_values(by = "Other",  ascending = False)["preference"].iloc[0:19] = df["Other"].sort_values( ascending = False).iloc[0:19]
```

But this is giving back no results at all. Can someone help me with this please? How can i obtain the desired result?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sorting and assign to original first:

```
df = df.sort_values(by = "Other",  ascending = False)
```

And then reaasign values with selecting by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html)

```
df.iloc[0:19, df.columns.get_loc("preference")] = df.iloc[0:19, df.columns.get_loc("Other")]
```

Or use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with select index values by indexing:

```
df.loc[df.index[0:19], "preference"] = df.loc[df.index[0:19], "Other"]
```